# Properly Format a Table With jQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table I am trying to populate with data I am pulling with AJAX. The data is in a JSON feed. I can populate the table half correct, but would appreciate some guidance on formatting it correctly.

The table currently looks like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9uwlge12n1skoxc/Screenshot%202019-04-04%2013.27.29.png?dl=0

The AJAX Call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'engine.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
             var data = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(data, function (k, v) {
                $('#fillinthedatahere').append('<td>'+v.symbol+'</td><td>'+v.timeframe+'</td><td>'+v.signal+'</td><td>'+v.dd+'</td><td>'+v.hd+'</td><td>'+v.opportunity+'</td><td>'+v.notes+'</td>');
            });
        }
    });

});
```

The Table:

```
 <table id="snapshot" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>Pair</td>
        <td>Timeframe</td>
        <td>Action</td>
        <td>Daily Direction</td>
        <td>Hourly Direction</td>
        <td>Opportunity</td>
        <td>Notes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="fillinthedatahere">

    </tr>
</table>
```

The way it is supposed to look is that each "pair" is supposed to have its own row. So row with pair 1 and all its data, row with pair 2 and all its data, and so on. I understand that the reason its all printing on one row instead of separate rows is because of the code I wrote, but I am unsure how to write it so it properly formats.

Appreciate anybody who can lead me in the correct direction!

Comment: If you know that you are just putting everything in separate columns what is stopping you from adding an if block in there to check some condition (like maybe a count of how many columns you have) to insert some `<tr>` tags around the columns that you want to group together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `fillinthedatahere` to a `<tbody>` then on each iteration open new html string with a  `<tr>` and close with `</tr>` so you create a new row for each object in array

```
 <table id="snapshot" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>Pair</td>
        <td>Timeframe</td>
        <td>Action</td>
        <td>Daily Direction</td>
        <td>Hourly Direction</td>
        <td>Opportunity</td>
        <td>Notes</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="fillinthedatahere">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
$.each(data, function(k, v) {
  $('#fillinthedatahere')
    .append('<tr><td>' + v.symbol + '</td>...<td>' + v.notes + '</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I see how close I was, and where I was making the mistake. Thank you!

Comment: This worked perfectly. I see how close I was, and where I was making the mistake. Thank you!